# Does increasing RAM increase speed of the computer

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will adding more RAM speed up My Computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/182084/will-adding-more-ram-speed-up-my-computer)

Hi  I have HP pavillion dm4 with 3GB RAM installed.
But in the task manager its always showing 48% used up if i am nt running any process then also its showing around 40%.  should i increase the RAM to 6GB?
will the speed of the computer increase by increasing the RAM?

Please give your suggestions

Thank You

Comment: There is no guarantee how much quicker it will be.  Your system has to support 6GB which is an odd number, you would be better off, going up to 8GB but your likely bottleneck is your processor.

Comment: Why is 6 GiB an odd number? Should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both yes and no. As your not using all available ram there wouldnt be much of a performance boost to increase the amount. However as windows 7 do cache quite a bit it might actelly speed it up slightly. Exactly on how much faster it would be, or if its fast enough to be worth it, that i dont know. My vote is on no, my old laptop worked fine with 2GB, my current one have 4GB and i cant say i noticed much of a performance difference (excluding heavy programs or gaming)

Answer (score 0):

The speed of your computer depends on a lot of things; RAM amount is one of them. But there are more considerations to it than just how much you have - if your system runs out of RAM, it will page to the hard disk instead, which makes it slower because the access time to your hard drive is significantly higher than the access time to the RAM.

Upping your system to 6GB of RAM might work, but only if it is a 64-bit operating system, with a 64-bit CPU. If it's 32-bit, the system can only address 4GB of memory due to the limitations of the architecture, meaning the other 2GB will be completely wasted.

Windows 7 comes with a light benchmarking tool in the control panel, under "Performance information and tools". There you can see a rough idea of where the bottleneck in your system's performance is. You can find out quickly if your system is a 64-bit operating system by looking at the C:\ drive - 64-bit versions of Windows come with two Program Files folders, one called "Program Files" where the 64-bit applications are kept, and one called "Program Files (x86)" where the 32-bit applications are kept. A 32-bit Windows installation only has "Program Files".

Answer (score 0):

Adding RAM will increase your speed but it also depends on the Processor and other factors including your hardware configuration. For example: If you're having a 3GB RAM for Core 2 Duo Processor and if you upgrade it to 4GB RAM your computer will have some increase in processing speed. But if you're upgrading it to 16GB RAM the speed will be same as that of the 4GB since it also depends on the 32-bit or 64-bit OS you're using and so on. Also, [Please refer this...](http://www.wisegeek.com/does-adding-ram-improve-computer-speed.htm)